# List sessions for multi-tenant application using subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a multi-tenant application using subdomain. For example, `foo.mydomain.com` for the *Foo* company and `bar.mydomain.com` for the *Bar* company.

Users are scoped by companies. So each user has to sign up/in for different companies. The whole mechanism is very similar to the one deployed by [Slack](http://slack.com).

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to manage users and sessions. The question is: how to list all companies user signed in so that they can switch subdomains/companies easily, just like how Slack let you switch teams.

Thanks a lot!